# MongoDB para dados de multi usuários

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, engenharia-de-software

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ao melhor estilo ERP, porém muito mais simples. 
É um programa do tipo MEAN (MongoDB, Express, Angular 2 e NodeJS) e também tem uma versão para Android feita com Ionic 2. Ainda está em faze de desenvolvimento, porém já está totalmente utilizável.

Para esta aplicação, como dito anteriormente, eu utilizei o banco de dados MongoDB. Além de, na minha opinião, ser mais fácil e rápido de desenvolver e ele se casa perfeitamente com o NodeJS e o Angular posteriormente.

O banco de dados se resume facilmente em 6 tabelas (coleções) onde cada uma delas apresenta uns 5 campos em média. Nada muito grande nem muito complicado. Com esse BD eu estou armazenando os dados para um Grupo no sistema. Porém a ideia é expandi-lo e permitir a criação de vários Grupos, onde em cada Grupo existem vários usuário no sistema, sendo que cada Grupo terá, obviamente, seus respectivos dados cadastrados.

Eu gostaria de saber como montar esse banco de dados com o MongoDB, não faço a menor ideia de como faze-la. Apenas pensei em adicionar a cada documento da coleção um ID para identificar quem é o Grupo que o dado pertence, e assim, no memento da busca, pegar os dados do usuário (que está dentro do em Grupo) que a requisitou e fazer um filtro.

**Algumas informações sobre o projeto:**

- Ele é baseado na Web e possuí também um app para Android (até o momento);
- Existem 2 tipos de usuário:

  **Normal:**  Apenas acessa os dados, não os manipula. Vê apenas os dados referentes ao seu grupo (e possui apenas um grupo);

  **Administrador:**  Acessa e manipula os dados. Só tem acesso aos dados do seu grupo (e cada grupo pode ter mais de um administrador, e cada Adm. também só possui um grupo).

Número de grupos: A estimativa é que ele possa chegar a ter 500 grupos;

Número de usuários Normais: Um para cada grupo apenas;

Número de usuário Administrativos: Um ou mais para cada grupo (sem limites).

Gostaria de uma dica de vocês! Será que devo trocar de banco?! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Paulo, vou trazer a recomendação que coloquei na resposta dessa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202936/relacionamento-1n-e-nm-mongodb-parse-server/202982#202982):

**Pense sempre em como os dados vão ser acessados/inseridos/atualizados.**

Diferente dos bancos relacionais, que são agnósticos em relação a quem e como os dados vão ser acessados, para aplicações usando MongoDB isso faz toda a diferença.

Lembra também do que você está abrindo mão escolhendo o MongoDB: integridade referencial, joins... isso é importante para a tua aplicação? ou a flexibilidade de esquema, escalabilidade são mais importantes?