# Relacionamento 1:N e N:M MongoDB parse-server

Tags: mongodb, entidade-relacionamento, parse.com

Eu tenho duas perguntas sobre como modelar um banco de dados mongo

1: 
Em 1: N, com mongodb, eu devo salvar na entidade filho o ID do objeto da entidade pai, ou a entidade pai salvar um Array com os IDs filho?

No Parse-Server eu não conseguia fazer o resultado voltar uma lista com os IDs na tabela pai, achei mais fácil o ID da filha  e pesquisar na tabela todos os resultados que têm o ID da tabela pai

2: 
Eu li sobre Many-to-many em mongo, mas, no meu db fiz como SQL, tenho uma terceira tabela que armazena o ID a partir das duas tabelas.

Ta certo? Pode causar erros ? Ou problemas de performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada não existe uma regra específica para modelagem em bancos noSQL. O que você encontra são recomendações na documentação do banco.

Falando sobre MongoDB, existe uma grande recomendação geral para seguir: **pense sempre em como os dados vão ser acessados/inseridos/atualizados**.

1. Nos relacionamentos 1:N, além de de seguir a regra geral, considere também de que tamanho esse N vai ser. Vai existir uma lista com dezenas/centenas de filhos? considera usar um subdocumento (sempre lembrando do tamanho máximo do documento de 16MB). Se o número de filhos for grande (milhares, milhões...), ou você sabe que vai crescer, é melhor usar uma collection separada. Falando da regra geral: seu acesso vai precisar dos filhos sempre? use um subdocumento. Você vai buscar o pai, e precisar dos filhos de vez em quando? use uma collection separada. As tuas propostas também são válidas, salvando os identificadores dos filhos no pai você consegue achar facilmente os filhos dos objetos, salvando o pai nos filhos você consegue "subir" no relacionamento de maneira fácil. Percebe como a maneira que você estrutura o esquema está relacionada diretamente a como você vai acessar ele.
2. Sobre o relacionamento N:N, é possível implementar como você fez sim. É possível também ter uma lista de identificadores dentro de cada objeto, dos dois lados. Aqui vale ainda mais a regra de como sua aplicação vai acessar a informação.